# How do you store raw bytes as text without losing information in python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, storage, bit, compression

Suppose I have any data stored in bytes.  For example:

> 0110001100010101100101110101101

How can I store it as *printable* text?  The obvious way would be to convert every 0 to the character '0' and every 1 to the character '1'. In fact this is what I'm currently doing.  I'd like to know how I could pack them more tightly, without losing information.

I thought of converting bits in groups of eight to ASCII, but some bit combinations are not
accepted in that format.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Which Python version?  3.0 has bytearrays separate from strings.

Comment: Regarding the ASCII problem, that's correct. ASCII is defined for integers up to 127 = 2^7 - 1. You should be packing groups of seven bits instead. But if you print out the corresponding ASCII code for every seven bits, you're just getting the identical binary file back again.

What's the difference between binary and text in your format? Who's doing the accepting? Why would that client want binary to be in text? For human-readability?

Comment: your question is not clear. data stored in bytes? is that a machine values or something else? what do you want to do with them? why don't you try archiver if you want to have a smaller size?

Comment: Thanks for your interest!

Lott: I'm using python 2.x
Lian: The bits I have are generated by a hashing function, so bits are sort of random (the 8-bit chunks can take any possible values)
I want to convertit to text to be able to send them via HTTP :P

Comment: You should consider that HTTP handles binary information fine. (Every cat photograph upload is a testament to that.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about an encoding that only uses "safe" characters like base64?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

EDIT: That is assuming that you want to safely store the data in text files and such?

In Python 2.x, strings should be fine (Python doesn't use null terminated strings, so don't worry about that).

Else in 3.x check out the bytes and bytearray objects.
http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-methods

Comment: does that encoding support any combination of 8 bits?
How could I turn bits to a Base64 char?

Comment: Check the wiki page, it basicly encodes any given binary data useing 64 charectors which are generally safe to send to/from web pages, in urls, text files etc. Obv for this reason though it uses one charector for every 6 bits (hence being called base64, 2^6 = 64)

Comment: I see.. I'll check that then... Thanks!

Comment: Might be simpler to just use `repr()` than base64.  Everything's escaped properly and the size doesn't grow quite as much.

Comment: Well I'm assuming if it had a sensible text representation he would have just used that in the first place rather than a string of 1's and 0's, and that his binary data is a video clip or some other binary thing like that.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you're talking about.

```
>>> sample = "".join( chr(c) for c in range(256) )
>>> len(sample)
256
>>> sample
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\
x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABC
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83
\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97
\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab
\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf
\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3
\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7
\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb
\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

The string `sample` contains all 256 distinct bytes.  There is no such thing as a "bit combinations ... not accepted".

To make it *printable*, simply use `repr(sample)` -- non-ASCII characters are escaped.  As you see above.

Comment: Although if hes using python 3.x which always uses unicode strings, its still going to be 4x (I think python uses UCS4 internally for unciode right?) the size it needs to be.

Comment: Unicode has nothing to do with it.  Each byte of `sample` has one of the 256 possible byte values. The question says "some bit combinations are not accepted", which is clearly not true.

Answer (score 1):

Try the standard *array* module or the *struct* module. These support storing bytes in a space efficient way -- but they don't support bits directly.

You can also try http://cobweb.ecn.purdue.edu/~kak/dist/BitVector-1.2.html or http://ilan.schnell-web.net/prog/bitarray/

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.x, your best bet is to store them in a string. Once you have that string, you can encode it into safe ASCII values using the base64 module that comes with python.

```
import base64
encoded = base64.b64encode(bytestring)
```

This will be much more condensed than storing "1" and "0".

For more information on the base64 module, see the python [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html).